# Excel 2010 custom ribbon visibility in .xlsm

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ribbonx

I have an Excel 2010 workbook with a custom ribbon but the ribbon is only visible while I'm on that workbook not when I switch to a different workbook.

Is there a way to change this and make it visible on all workbooks?

I know I can save the workbook as an add-in and eventually that will be the case but while I'm developing it would be handy for me to just to be able to see the ribbon on all workbooks.

Thanks for your help

Simon

Comment: If you create a custom group, and add it to, say, the Home ribbon, it stays there forever.  It's not attached to the workbook.

Comment: Not ideal but it will have to do!

Thanks durbnpoisn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting as actual answer, as it appears to be accepted.

If you create a custom group, and add it to, say, the Home ribbon, it stays there forever. It's not attached to the workbook.